# A single Nokogiri rake task to scrape all Groupon deals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I want to scrape Groupon deals using Nokogiri. I want to scrape all these deals at the following link:
http://www.groupon.com/getaways?d=travel_countmein

On top of that, I want to access each individual link and scrape the title and price. Conceptually, is there a way to code a single rake task to do this?

I understand that there needs to be a loop of some sort, but I don't know how to parse the url for each deal from the main getaway page.

I've already written a scraper for the title and price:

```
task :fetch_travel => :environment do

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.groupon.com/deals/ga-flamingo-conferences-resort-spa?c=all&p=0"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))


title = doc.at_css("#content//h2/a").text
price = doc.at_css("#amount").text[/[0-9\.]+/]
link = doc.at_css("#content//h2/a")[:href]
desc = doc.at_css(".descriptor").text

Traveldeal.create(:title => title, :price => price, :url => link, :description => desc)

end
```

Comment: You can just enter a fake email and it will take you directly to the mentioned page.

Comment: This shows no attempt to solve the problem. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: @theTinMan this question is 7 years old my dude.

Comment: Time doesn't change whether a question is asked well. It's part of the culling process on SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out that this requires nested loop where the inner loop is the code above and the outer loop will parse each deal for the url to be used in the inner loop.

Comment: An answer to the question should supply some example code. A description does little good: Code, like a picture, is worth 10,000 words.